# java database mismatch and error handling

Tags: java, jdbc, error-handling

Need to return

> "Timestamp do not match for id: "+ id

if timestamp match or not in database for below code.
What is standard practice for that?

```
public void update(User entity) throws Exception {
    try(Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection()){
        String sql = "UPDATE USERS SET " +
                "FLAG = ?" +
                "WHERE ID = ? " +
                "AND LASTUPDATEDTIMESTAMP = ?";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setBoolean(1, entity.getFlag());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, entity.getId());
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(entity.getLastUpdatedTimestamp()));
        int updateCount = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        //logic here

    }catch(SqlException e){
      // method here
    }
}
```

Comment: if id is the primary key, you can try something like this UPDATE USERS SET FLAG = ?, LASTUPDATEDTIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ID = ?;

Comment: When you say "return", do you mean you want to throw an exception with the given text? Because you can't *return* anything from a `void` method.

Comment: U can change the method if required, I want to know proper way to handle such cases. Let say "last timestamp not mathc" is different than "ID not mathc ". THese are not exception, just queery can't find a record for it in DB. I need to display what issue is. SO looking to handle such cases